# How can I load the CSS file with HTML in Swift 3?

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, swift3

I have an HTML file which is being displayed fine on my device but it does not load the CSS file in it on my device. When I do open the HTML on my browser, my CSS is working fine.

This is my HTML code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Prateek Bhatt</h1>
    <br>
    <p>is the greatest</p>
</body>
```

This is my CSS file named stylesheet.css:

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
    color: navy;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Also this is the code for Swift 3:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
        let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }    
}
```

Comment: Also I am new to ios so I do not know very much about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these four steps to load a `CSS` file in a `WebView`:

**Step 1:**
Access the local `CSS` file from the `Bundle`.
`guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Style", ofType: "css") else { return }`

**Step 2:**
Get the `CSS` content in `String` format.
`let cssString = try! String(contentsOfFile: path).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)`

**Step 3:**
Write your `JavaScript` in a string to be evaluated later by the `WebView`.
`let jsString = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(cssString)'; document.head.appendChild(style);"`

**Step 4:** Render the JavaScript.
`webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)`

> DOCUMENTATION
>
> - **Framework:** `WebKit`
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/
> - **Class:** `WKWebView`
>   [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/)
> - **Instance Method:** `evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)`
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript

Comment: I tried what you wrote but I got this error. 
 
I got error in this line-
webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)

the error is - value of type 'UIwebView' has no member 'evaluateJavaScript'

Comment: Please check EDIT section.